# Problemas salto de linea php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema cuando intento concatenar el salto de linea de mis arrays asociativos no me deja y me sale este error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''
> ''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in
>   C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\xamp\htdocs\posible.php on line 3

```
    <?php
$lluvias = array(
     'Campo 1'=> array('zona1'=>53 ," , ", 'zona2'=>23," , ", 'zona3'=>65.'<br>'),
     'Campo 2'=>array('zona4'=>60 ," , ", 'zona5'=>70," , ", 'zona6'=>80.'<br>'),
     'Campo 3'=>array('zona7'=>13 ," , ", 'zona8'=>63," , ", 'zona9'=>50.'<br>')





      );

     //$nota=$calificacion['Por parcial']['Parcial 1'];
foreach ($lluvias as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'<br>';

    foreach ($value as $key2 ) {
        print_r($key2).'<br>';
    }
}

    $promediocamp1=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 1'])/count($lluvias['Campo 1']['zona1'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 1
       echo "El promedio de lluvias  por zona en el   campo 1 es de :".$promediocamp1.'<br>';

     $promediocamp2=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 2'])/count($lluvias['Campo 2']['zona4'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 2
        echo "El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 2 es de :".$promediocamp2.'<br>';

      $promediocamp3=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 3'])/count($lluvias['Campo 3']['zona7'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 3
          echo "El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 3 es de :".$promediocamp3.'<br>';

       $promediogene=($promediocamp1+$promediocamp2+$promediocamp3)/3;                       //promedio general de la matriz
       echo "El promedio de todos los datos almacenados en la matriz es de : ".$promediogene;


?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Tu array es algo *desastroso*, con todo respeto.

Recomiendo que leas [lo que dice el Manual sobre los arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php), y para tu caso específico, el **Ejemplo 14**.

Un array debe tener al menos un par de `clave` => `valor` asociados. Dicha condición no se cumple en tu caso. También pueden haber otros array dentro del array principal.

El problema es que, al parecer, intentas crear un array como si se tratase de un `echo`.

<s>Campo 1'=> array('zona1'=>53 ," , ", 'zona2'=>23," , ", 'zona3'=>65.'
')</s>

Cuando se trata de arrays, no tiene sentido agregar elementos html al array, como los elementos `<br>`, o agregar comas entre comillas `","` ¿? ...  ya que eso lo puedes poner cuando lees el array, como bien haces en tus bucles for y demás.

Vamos a construir un array menos *desastre*  :)  y luego lo leeremos.

Sólo voy a modificar la parte de array, el resto del código no tiene cambios y verás que funciona.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente, de cada clave del array quito los elementos que sobran. Por ejemplo, esto:

```
 'Campo 1'=> array('zona1'=>53 ," , ", 'zona2'=>23," , ", 'zona3'=>65.'<br>'),
```

quedará convertido en esto:

```
 'Campo 1'=> array('zona1'=>53 , 'zona2'=>23, 'zona3'=>65),
```

Lo cual quiere decir que el array `$lluvias` tiene un elemento cuya clave se llama `Campo1` y dicho elemento a su vez tiene otro array con tres claves: `zona1`con un valor de 53, `zona2`con valor de 23 y `zona3` con valor de 65.

Lo mismo ocurre con los otros elementos...

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/YTC22924)

```
<?php 

$lluvias = array ( 
                "Campo 1"  => array ( 
                                        "zona1" => 53,
                                        "zona2" => 23,
                                        "zona3" => 65
                                     ),

                "Campo 2"  => array ( 
                                        "zona4" => 60,
                                        "zona5" => 70,
                                        "zona6" => 80
                                     ),

                "Campo 3"  => array ( 
                                        "zona7" => 13,
                                        "zona8" => 63,
                                        "zona9" => 50
                                     )

);



foreach ($lluvias as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'<br>';

    foreach ($value as $key2 ) {
        echo($key2).'<br>';
    }
}


$promediocamp1=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 1'])/count($lluvias['Campo 1']['zona1'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 1
echo "El promedio de lluvias  por zona en el   campo 1 es de :".$promediocamp1.'<br>';

$promediocamp2=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 2'])/count($lluvias['Campo 2']['zona4'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 2
echo "El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 2 es de :".$promediocamp2.'<br>';

$promediocamp3=array_sum($lluvias['Campo 3'])/count($lluvias['Campo 3']['zona7'])/3;  //promedio de lluvias campo 3
echo "El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 3 es de :".$promediocamp3.'<br>';

$promediogene=($promediocamp1+$promediocamp2+$promediocamp3)/3;                       //promedio general de la matriz
echo "El promedio de todos los datos almacenados en la matriz es de : ".$promediogene;

?>
```

#### `Resultado`:

```html
Campo 1<br>53<br>23<br>65<br>Campo 2<br>60<br>70<br>80<br>Campo 3<br>13<br>63<br>50<br>El promedio de lluvias  por zona en el   campo 1 es de :47<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 2 es de :70<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 3 es de :42<br>El promedio de todos los datos almacenados en la matriz es de : 53
```

Si quieres colocar un `<br>` después del nombre de cada clave: `Campo1, Campo2, Campo n` lo puedes hacer simplemente colocando un `<br>` antes del nombre de la clave en el bucle for:

```
foreach ($lluvias as $key => $value) {
    echo '<br>'.$key.'<br>';
...
```

```html
<br>Campo 1<br>53<br>23<br>65<br><br>Campo 2<br>60<br>70<br>80<br><br>Campo 3<br>13<br>63<br>50<br>El promedio de lluvias  por zona en el   campo 1 es de :47<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 2 es de :70<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 3 es de :42<br>El promedio de todos los datos almacenados en la matriz es de : 53
```

O puedes rodearlo por líneas usando `<hr>`:

```
foreach ($lluvias as $key => $value) {
    echo '<hr>'.$key.'<hr>';
...
```

```html
<hr>Campo 1<hr>53<br>23<br>65<br><hr>Campo 2<hr>60<br>70<br>80<br><hr>Campo 3<hr>13<br>63<br>50<br>El promedio de lluvias  por zona en el   campo 1 es de :47<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 2 es de :70<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el  campo 3 es de :42<br>El promedio de todos los datos almacenados en la matriz es de : 53
```

O... más flexible aún, puedes aplicar reglas CSS:

```
foreach ($lluvias as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="espacio">'.$key.'</div>';
...
```

```css
.espacio {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="espacio">Campo 1</div>53<br>23<br>65<br>
<div class="espacio">Campo 2</div>60<br>70<br>80<br>
<div class="espacio">Campo 3</div>13<br>63<br>50<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el campo 1 es de :47<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el campo 2 es de :70<br>El promedio de lluvias por zona en el campo 3 es de :42<br>El promedio de todos los datos almacenados
en la matriz es de : 53
```

---

#### En conclusión

Mientras más limpio esté tu array, mejor. Lo demás lo haces de forma dinámica, **al momento de leer el array**.

Comment: Amigo enserio muchísimas gracias por tus explicaciones y consejos , en este momento aprendí como ser mas pulcro a la hora de escribir códigos te lo agradezco de verdad :D

Comment: De  nada @DANIELFELIPELOPEZVARGAS Si la respuesta ha servido como solución al problema puedes marcarla como solución, de modo que no aparezca como sin resolver. Saludos.